# LOOKUP_KEY and CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI

Tags: android, uri

I have the following code to get details of a contact.
"data": is the Uri I get back after selecting the contact.

I need to be sure that I will get to the right contact in the future so what should I be saving for future use? Is it "lookupUri" or "lookupKey"?

```
    Cursor c =  activity.managedQuery(data, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    String lookupKey = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY ));
    c.close();

    // Next use that key to access the details of the contact in order to get the name and the photo
    // Also, save it for future use.
    // It will be used when we fetch the details from the database since the photo itself is not saved.
     Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI,lookupKey);

    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.lookupContact(activity.getContentResolver(), deviceDetails.lookupUri);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LookupKey is the unique identifier that you want to store.

FYI; There is a bug in 2.1 where un-synced contacts LookupKey changes when the name is changed.

Answer (score 0):

This works.  My example looks up the name; add or remove the fields you want in the projection.

```
private String getContactNameFromAndroidKey (String key)
{
  // Run query
  Uri uri = Uri.parse (ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI + "/" + key);

  String[] projection = new String[] {
    Contacts._ID,
    Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
  };

  Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query (
    uri,
    projection,
    null,
    null,
    null);

  if (!cursor.moveToNext()) // move to first (and only) row.
    throw new IllegalStateException ("contact no longer exists for key");
  String name = cursor.getString(1);
  cursor.close();

  return name;
}
```

Comment: key is "LOOKUP_KEY"